# Problems with torrents

Tags: router

I have the Cisco Linksys X2000. I have it on my PC an i have an ethernet cable on it with wich i give internet to my neigbour. Problem is he is kinda overuse my kindness and he uses it to download torrents 24/7.

My question is. Is there someway (from windows or router settings, or from Kaspersky Internet Security or even with a third party app) to ban the use of torrents and just let him have access to web pages etc?

Thank you in advance

PS. If it cant be done i would be glad if someone can suggest to me a router that can do it not very expensive

Comment: If it was me, I'd merely unplug the ethernet cable.

Comment: Honestly, anything we suggest will require some reading and effort on your part, [so might I suggest you start with the site FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq)?

Comment: This was closed due to the "Anything in a home setting" exclusion in the FAQ.

Comment: @tombull89 is right. You don't need a technical solution here. Talk to the neighbor. Tell him to stop torrenting, and make it clear that you'll stop providing *free internet* if he doesn't.